# Salesforce integration with External Services Using Access Token

Tags: automation, jwt, salesforce, integration, outbound

An External Service requires me to generate access token using a Post Token Issue request

```
POST /api/Token/Issue HTTP/1.1

Host: <Your environment>

Authorization: Basic <ClientID/UserID:password>

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Content-Length: 0
```

I need the access token to make subsequent request

```
POST /api/Lists/Search HTTP/1.1

Host: <Your environment>

Authorization: Bearer <JSON web token/ access token>

Content-Type: application/json

API-Key: <Your Client Instance API Key>

{"":""}
```

How can I automate the process in Salesforce using Flows to generate the access token and also make use of the access token for the subsequent Post Lists Search request?

I tried building a flow that issues the token and output it.